# In a C# class library, closing a WPF LogWatcher Window in its own thread, stops the main thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I wrote a C# COM exposed class library. I call its exposed methods from third party software.

I wrote a WPF dialog to watch the log entries as the business logic is performed.
The WPF dialog is started on a separate thread, prior to starting the actual method generating log entries. This is working pretty good.

The issue I have is that if I close the logwatcher window ***before*** to the main method `DoTheActualWorkAsync()` is finished, the `DoTheActualWorkAsync()` method stops running and the methods seems deadlocked.

Any ideas how to solve this? Why does closing a WPF window in a separate thread freeze the main thread?

This is my code:

```
// Exposed Method
public void DoALotOfWorkWrapper()
{
    // Start WPF LogWatchWindow on new thread
    var logWatcherThread = this.GetLogWatcherThread();
    
    // Peform a lot of business logic, block for procedure to be ready
    DoTheActualWorkAsync().Wait();
    
    // Join logwatcher thread so method doesn't finish before window is closed
    WaitForLogWatcherThread(logWatcherThread);
}

private Thread GetLogWatcherThread()
{
    var signalEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    var logWatchWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var vm = new LogWatchWindowViewModel();
        var win = new LogWatchWindow
        {
            DataContext = vm
        };
        win.Show();
        vm.HookupLog4NetEvents(win);

        win.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
        {
            vm.DetachLog4NetEvents();
            win.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        };

        signalEvent.Set();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });

    logWatchWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    logWatchWindowThread.Start();

    // Block to wait for Window and its viewmodel to be ready for displaying new log4net entries
    signalEvent.WaitOne();
    signalEvent.Reset();

    return logWatchWindowThread;
}

private static void WaitForLogWatcherThread(Thread logWatcherThread)
{
    logWatcherThread.Join();
}
```

Comment: This will be guesswork. But for the LogWatchWindow to show anything, messages need to be dispatched to that thread. If the window is closed, whatever component that is doing the logging might deadlock/hang since it tries to dispatch messages to a dispatcher that no longer exist. Is there any reason you are using this approach rather than the more common UI on a single UI thread, and background work on threadpool threads?

Comment: Thanks, `since it tries to dispatch messages to a dispatcher that no longer exist` was my clue. The LogWatcherViewModel added a MemoryAppender to log4net hierarchy. When win.Close triggered, it removed that appender, causing the dll to hang. I now attach the MemoryAppender not in the logwatcher viewmodel, but in the parent GetLogWatcherThread() method, and I remove the appender in WaitForLogWatcherThread(), which only runs when the blocking DoTheActualWorkAsync().Wait() is finished. That way the appender is not removed while other threads are in the process of writing log messages to it.